# rounded image in ring with shadow

Tags: android, android-layout

We know that to create this kind of shadow

[image]

this kind of xml should be used.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <layer-list>
            <item android:left="4dp" android:top="4dp">
                <shape>
                    <solid android:color="#ff58bb52" />
                    <corners android:radius="30dip"/>
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
    <item>
        <layer-list>
            <!-- SHADOW LAYER -->
            <item android:left="4dp" android:top="4dp">
                <shape>
                    <solid android:color="#66000000" />
                    <corners android:radius="30dip"/>
                </shape>
            </item>
            <!-- CONTENT LAYER -->
            <item android:bottom="4dp" android:right="4dp">
                <shape>
                    <solid android:color="#ff58bb52" />
                    <corners android:radius="30dip"/>
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
</selector>
```

But we'd like to implement the following design.

[image]

Can this be implemented using layers?

Answer (score 0):

To make circular background use one linear layout set background to it

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/inf_gird_Parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_bg2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

       <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/android" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

and make one drawble `circle_bg2.xml`

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <corners android:radius="10dip" />
    <stroke
        android:width="2dip"
        android:color="@color/white" />

    <size
        android:width="100dp"
        android:height="100dp" />

    <solid android:color="my Green Color" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what you are looking for

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item >
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_green_light"/>
            <stroke android:width="2dip" android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
        </shape>  
    </item>
   <item >
       <bitmap android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:gravity="center"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

just replace the `android:src="YOUR-IMAGE"` 
and the colors as per design

Hope this helps :)